# How can I Connect 2 different projects to the same Development Environment DB?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, h2, grails-domain-class, in-memory-database

I have 2 projects A an B

and they have a domain class called "TABLE"

A is going to insert the information in "TABLE" an B has to Select it

I have this configuration in the first project's `DataSource.groovy`:

```
enviroments{
    development{
       dataSource {
              url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
       }
    }
}
```

It's running in memory and in the port 8110, how can I access to that DB from the other application? something like

```
url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8110/mem:devDb" //?
```

Comment: I dont't understand what you see as a problem? Just put same connection configuration into both projects..

Comment: dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"

Actually they have the same url but they are running in different ports

Comment: You want to share in-memory database among the projects? I'm afraid that's not going to work.. Another thing I don't understand is the architecture - you will have two different databases running on two ports?

Comment: Exactly, the deal is that I want to migrate information from one DB to another, so I got information from some where, then that information is what I want to save in "TABLE" (and I want that this table to be in the other application's connection to test it with this new application). I have this projects running in development mode in different ports.

Answer (score 1):

The ports and locations where the application is running is irrelevant so long as both instances of the application have access to the database.

Based on the small bit of information that you are presenting, I assume that what you want is to set up multiple data sources. You can go to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) for additional details but here is a teaser:

In DataSource.groovy:

```
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        // Connection parameters for the application specific dataSource
    }
    dataSource_common {
        // Connection parameters for the common dataSource
    }
}

// Copy and paste for other environments
}
```

In your domain class:

```
class Table {
   // Domain Class properties

   static mapping = {
      datasource 'common'
   }
}
```

For both applications, make the Table class identical. When application A saves an instance of Table then it will be available for both applications. Application B can then read from the table.

**A word of caution:**

Its generally bad practice to have two application working with the same datasource. The above directions explain how to allow multiple applications to access a single datasource but do not encourage you to do so.

Rather than having a common datasource you should probably have application A expose the Table domain class through a RESTful interface to object B. This would alleviate potential conflicts caused by two instances of Hibernate manipulating the same structure and dataset.

You can find additional details about Grails RESTful resource exposure in the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#REST).

Comment: But If I run both apps at the same time can I manipulate the table from the 2 apps?

Comment: Of course you can. But you can run into race/locking problems. Its safer to let one application have exclusive access to the datasource.

Comment: Yes, It could work if I'd have a connection to a particular DB, but the deal is that I want to manipulate the Table in the DEFAULT Environment development Data base:

    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"

And just like it, I can see that I refresh the table from localhost:8081/Project/dbConsole and in  localhost:8081/Project2/dbConsole and the information in the tables are not the same

Comment: if your 2nd app is only accessing your datastore for reading it's ok, hence you don'need to use optmistic/pessmistic locking on both DB..

Answer (score 0):

I found the way:

I had to create a TCP connection in `Conf->spring->resources.groovy`, here is the link:

http://rudovsky.blogspot.com/2012/09/parametrize-grails-h2-server.html